# Can the random seed be controlled from shogun's python interface?

Tags: python, shogun

Using shogun 6.1.3 and python 3.6.

I am trying to get replicable results in shogun for testing purposes, but I do not see a way to control the random seed.

I have tried:

```
import random
import numpy
from shogun import KMeans

random.seed(0)
numpy.random.seed(0)
km = KMeans(seed=0)
```

I am wanting to do this for many shogun algorithms, but here is simple example using KMeans:

```py
from shogun import KMeans, RealFeatures, MulticlassLabels, EuclideanDistance
import numpy

trainX = numpy.array([[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0]] * 3).astype(float)
trainY = numpy.array([[0], [1], [2]] * 3).astype(float).flatten()
testX = numpy.array([[0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0]]).astype(float)

Xtrain = RealFeatures(trainX.T)
Ytrain = MulticlassLabels(trainY)
Xtest = RealFeatures(testX.T)

km = KMeans()
km.set_distance(EuclideanDistance(Xtrain, Xtrain))
km.train(Xtrain)
labs = km.apply_multiclass(Xtest)
labs.get_labels()
```

`labs.get_labels()` is different each time, but I believe setting the random seed should yield a consistent result.  Is there an attribute I can set, or some other way to control the randomness and get a consistent result?

Comment: Wanted to add (since I used 0 in the post) that the seed 0 seems to have no effect but 1 through (2**32) - 1 create reproducible results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Shogun 6.1.3 (and earlier versions), you can use a (global) static call `Math.init_random(seed)`.

Since having a global seed leads to reproducibility issues in multi-threaded settings, in the develop branch of Shogun, we have recently removed this. Instead you can set the seed (recursively) of particular objects using `obj.put("seed", my_seed)`. Or, even simpler, using kwargs style initializers in Python: `km = sg.machine("KMeans", k=2, distance=d, seed=1)`.

Both of those are documented in the generated meta examples, using the 6.1.3 and develop branch respectively. The website examples will be updated with the next release.

Comment: Great! This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: is there any way to get/set the random state?

Comment: In Shogun 6.1.3 (and earlier), this is not possible. In future versions (where each object has its own random state), this might (or might not) be added. Please check the release notes for future versions for that.